# NHibernate session in BusinessLogic with lazy loading

Tags: c#, nhibernate, session, n-tier-architecture, business-logic

I am currently developing a middle sized application. The application will have a n-tier structure with different presentation tiers. One part will be a web application but it is likely that there will be other parts dealing with, for instance, sensor communication (for which it is not clear how it will be developed at this stage).

My question is if it is possible to use NHibernate directly in the business logic layer and let the business logic provide the upper and horizontal layers/parts with requested data when having lazy-loading.

Is it possible to initialize the session in the business layer and still have lazy-loading? In that case, how would the session be handled? Is it possible to wrap the requested data together with the session so that the session is alive as long as the object is alive?

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question fully, but from what I gather, you're asking whether you can use lazy-loading when your client is other than web client.
The answer is yes; it doesn't matter how or where your `Session` was initialized.

Using nHib directly in the business layer is considered best practise by some (including myself).

Concerning your question about 'wrap the requested data together with the session so that the session is alive as long as the object is alive'-
I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean sending your Model classes along with the session so that your client can lazily load their properties- I would strongly recommend not going there.
A rule of thumb is that you give the client **only** what it needs to have, and nothing more.
(Ayende [elaborates](http://ayende.com/blog/4011/the-stripper-pattern) on this.)
For that reason, I think you should always communicate with your client using DTOs.

The way I would set this up is:
Client requests data from server => server loads the object (but does not initialize lazy-loaded properties), populates a DTO and returns it to the client.

Client requests a lazy-loaded property => server loads the object (using either nHib's 2nd level [cache](http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/28/first-and-second-level-caching-in-nhibernate), or some other caching mechanism) ,loads the requested property and returns a DTO to the client.